# Serialize Java 8 Stream with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, java-8, jersey-2.0

How can I serialize a Java 8 `java.util.Stream<T>` with Jersey. I tried to write a `MessageBodyWriter`, but I need to know how to compose (decorate) existing `MessageBodyWriters` with a new `MessageBodyWriter` for my `Stream`.

```
Stream<String> get(){
  return some stream of strings  
}

public <T> class StreamMessageBodyWriter<Stream<T>> 
           implements MessageBodyWriter<Stream<T>> {

  public void writeTo(.......){
    //How can I get the handle to MessageBodyWriter that will write for type T, 
    //so that I can 'collect' the 'java.util.Stream<T>' and write it to 
    //OutputStream
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I need to know how to compose (decorate) existing `MessageBodyWriters` with a new `MessageBodyWriter` for my `Stream`

You can just inject [`Providers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers.html) and use [`getMessagBodyWriter(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers.html#getMessageBodyWriter%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation%5B%5D,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29), passing in the required details to lookup the specific writer for that type. For example

```
@Provider
public class StreamBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Stream> {
    
    @Context
    private Providers providers;

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Stream.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Stream stream, Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) { return -1; }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Stream stream, Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, 
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
     
        Object obj = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        Class<?> objType = obj.getClass();
        
        MessageBodyWriter writer = providers.getMessageBodyWriter(objType, 
                null, annotations, mediaType);
        
        writer.writeTo(obj, objType, null, annotations, 
                mediaType, httpHeaders, entityStream);
        
    }
}
```

If you look at the `writeTo`, first I call `collect` then get the returned type. Then lookup the writer for that type, then simply delegate to the writer.

Here is a test

```
@Path("stream")
public class StreamResource {
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getStream() {
        List<Person> myList = Arrays.asList(
                              new Person("Stack"), 
                              new Person("Overflow"),
                              new Person("Sam"));
        Stream<Person> stream = myList.stream()
                                      .filter(p -> p.name.startsWith("S"));
        return Response.ok(stream).build();
    }
    
    public static class Person {
        public String name;
        public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
        public Person() {}
    }
}
```

> `C:\>curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/stream`
> **Result:**
> `[{"name":"Stack"},{"name":"Sam"}]`

As an aside, if you plan on manipulating the Stream in the writer, maybe look into using an [Interceptor](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9712). Won't make a difference really, but if you want to stick to the Single Responsibility Principle, this is what the `Interceptor` is for, manipulating the request body.

---

Note: the above is standard JAX-RS

#### Alternatively...

Specifically with Jersey, you can also inject [`MessageBodyWorkers`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.16/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/message/MessageBodyWorkers.html), for more specific lookup, and even calling its `writeTo`, which will delegate to the required writer, if one exsists.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The Providers injection is what I was looking for. I still need to find a way of not collecting the list as I want to avoid realizing a list into memory, but that is something I will work on. This really helps.

Comment: The `stream.collect(Collectors.toList())` defeats the purpose of using streams. If I have a stream with a huge number of elements I can't assemble them all into an in memory collection; that's one of the reasons to use Java 8 streams in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the purpose of use streams (without using `stream.collect(Collectors.toList())`), there's this interesting article showing [how to serialize large data from a database](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/07/how-to-streamserialize-jpa-result-as-jax-rs-response-for-large-data.html).

It's something like this...

```
@GET
@Produces( "application/json" )
public Response streamGeneratedUuids() {

    return getNoCacheResponseBuilder( Response.Status.OK ).entity( new StreamingOutput() {

        @Override
        public void write( OutputStream os ) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os))) ) {
                //iterate the java.util.stream and write to the OutputStream
                writer.print("....");       
            }
        }
    }).build();
}
```

It's not implemented with a MessageBodyWriter, but could adapted in my opinion.