# Supply Polymorphic De-serialization/Serialization parameters to REST endpoint without changing POJOs

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I am working on a `JAX-RS` application, where endpoints Consume and Produce `JSON` type data. And I am using `Jackson` for that purpose.

As I know one of the ways to handle Polymorphic behavior in `Jackson` is to use `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` on POJOs.

But in my case POJOs are not part of code, they're embedded in a JAR file and I can't edit them.

Is there any way where I can specify this info to `Jackson` externally without POJO annotations ?

Please point me to the right direction of this has already been discussed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way where I can specify this info to Jackson externally without POJO annotations?

Using annotations is still a valid approach if you consider *mix-in annotations*.

When modifying the source code is not an option, you can use *mix-in annotations* to add [Jackson annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) to a bean. You can think of it as kind of aspect-oriented way of adding more annotations during runtime, to augment statically defined ones.

First define a mix-in annotation interface or class:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "class")
public interface FooMixIn {

}
```

Then configure `ObjectMapper` to use the defined interface as a mix-in for your POJO:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().addMixIn(Foo.class, FooMixIn.class);
```

All [annotation sets](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) that Jackson recognizes can be mixed in. For more details, have a look at the Jackson [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).