# How to find the deserializer used by jersey

Tags: java, api, jersey, jackson, moxy

In our jersey project, we are using 2 json providers, Moxy and Jackson. I want to know which provider is being used to deserialize my payload, whether its Moxy or Jackosn. Is there any way to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *are* ways to find it, but it unnecessary, as generally, the same one will be used. The way Jersey (2.x) is set up, is that MOXy (`jersey-media-moxy`) is the default provider. If you have both on the classpath, *without* any further configuration, MOXy will be used.

There are a couple of ways to disable MOXy. Either explicitly register the `JacksonFeature` (that comes with `jersey-media-json-jackson`), or set the property [`ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.19/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE) to `true`

But just for completeness, the couple ways I can think of top of my head to figure out which one is being used

- Trigger an exception and handle it in a mapper. Check the stack trace. (I know not very elegant)
- Write a `ContextResolver` for the `ObjectMapper`. If Jackson is being used, the `getContext` method will be called (just add an s.o.p). [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310779/2587435)
- You could retrieve the provider through the injectable `Providers` interface. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29226591/2587435)

There are probably other ways, but like I said, it doesn't really seem necessary. You should already know.